# MVC reading multiple controls to a list - (posting elements with same name with special MVC formatting)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post

[Screen shot of the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrWVq.png)

I want to post multiple elements with same name to server, how to read the list to a collection, the control names names are formatted with special format found in a blog, still not able to access the data.

```
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="[1].SpecificationTitle" />                              
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="[1].SpecificationDescription" />

<input type="text" class="inputs" name="[2].SpecificationTitle" />                              
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="[2].SpecificationDescription" />
```

Reading

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addBuyOnlinepostA(ICollection<SpecificationDetails> SpecificationDetails, FormCollection Collection)
    {
    }

   public class SpecificationDetails
    {
        public string SpecificationTitle { get; set; }
        public string SpecificationDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Indexers need to start a zero and be consecutive) (and remove the pointless `FormCollection Collection` parameter)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will test this later, I used a temporary method to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use jquery/Ajax to get the data and then post it to server side.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {

        data = $(".inputs").map(function () { return $(this).val();});
        var data2 = data.toArray();
        alert(data2);
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
            traditional: true,
            data: {Data:data2 },
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
            });

        function successFunc(data) {

            alert("success");
        }
        function errorFunc(data) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

```
 <input type="text" class="inputs" name="[1].SpecificationTitle" />
 <input type="text" class="inputs" name="[1].SpecificationDescription" />
 <input type="text" class="inputs" name="[2].SpecificationTitle" />
 <input type="text" class="inputs" name="[2].SpecificationDescription" />

 <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>`
```

Comment: @Sudhashnu  I want write minimum code as possible, my method would eliminate server side validation etc with very less effort